# How to get minimum count,maximum count and total result set count from a result set

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need to get minimum count,maximum count  and total result set count from a result set. After executing the query it produces multiple rows and i need to extract data from that.
Eg query :

```
SELECT count(*) AS `countTotal`,`admission_no`,`course`  FROM  `attendance` WHERE  `course` = '15' AND `timestamp` AND  `admission_no` !='0' AND `timestamp` BETWEEN '2016-04-01 00:00:00.0' AND '2017-03-31 00:00:00.0' GROUP BY `admission_no` ORDER BY `countTotal`  DESC
```

OUT PUT

```
countTotal  admission_no    course
4            2304             15
4            2442             15
3            2777             15
2            2967             15
2            3288             15
```

I tried this:

```
if (overallTotalClassRow.next()) {
    maxclassaverage = overallTotalClassRow.getInt(1);
}
```

But this will give the maximum value. i.e 4.

I need to get 4 and 2 as maximum and minimum and total count as 5. How could i do that.. Any Help will appreciated.

Comment: 'And timestamp' will always be true. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Maybe he is checking the timestamp is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This.

```
        select min(countTotal) as MinCount ,max(countTotal) as MaxCount, 
        count(*) as totalCount  from
        (SELECT count(*) AS `countTotal`,`admission_no`,`course` 
         FROM  `attendance` WHERE  `course` = '15' AND `timestamp` 
         AND  `admission_no` !='0' AND `timestamp` 
         BETWEEN '2016-04-01 00:00:00.0' AND '2017-03-31 00:00:00.0' 
         GROUP BY `admission_no` 
         )a
```

and then use

Comment: error is showing : Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Wow!! It worked like charm.. Most easiest way rather than from java.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Most Welcome  @KarthikCP

Answer (score 1):

> Java approach:-

1) Put the countTotal in an ArrayList
2) Use the Collections class max and min methods to find maximum and minimum.
example:-

```
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2));
        }
    };
int max=Collections.max(list, comparator);
```

3) ArrayList.size() to find the total count.

> SQL approach:-

Use the max, min and total count queries in union.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is:

```
int maximum = 0;
int minimum =0;
int totalCount =0;

if (overallTotalClassRow.next()) {
    totalCount +=1;
    if(totalCount ==1) {
        maximum = overallTotalClassRow.getInt(1);
        minimum = overallTotalClassRow.getInt(1);
    }
    if (overallTotalClassRow.getInt(1)> maximum) {
        maximum = overallTotalClassRow.getInt(1); 
    }
    if (overallTotalClassRow.getInt(1)< maximum) {
        minimum = overallTotalClassRow.getInt(1); 
    }
}
```